# Set custom field value when reaching expiration date

Tags: custom-field, sticky-post

I had the idea to make sticky posts expire after a certain period of time.

FYI, I am using a custom post type along with custom field suite and created sticky posts by creating a boolean custom field. `premium` is a true/false custom field which returns the value `1` if the checkbox is checked (which makes a post a featured post)

If I created another custom field to set the expiration date, how would I set the sticky-custom-field value to 0 when the expiration date is reached?

What I mean is (in written english):

- check for a custom field with the key "premium"
- check if custom field "premium" has value 1
- check for a custom field with the key "expiration_date"
- check if "expiration_date" value is in the past, but not today
- if "expiration_date" is in the past, set "premium" value to 0

Can someone assist making this a function?

I'd begin with the following (please excuse the style, I am just trying to provide ideas)

```
global $post;
global $cfs;
if ( '1' = $cfs->get('premium') && ' ' != $cfs->get('expiration_date') ) :
$current_date = date(Y-m-d);
$expiration_date = $cfs->get('expiration_date');
if( // I'm stuck here... ) ....
date_post_meta( $post->ID, 'premium', '1', '0' ); // set premium field from 1 to 0 for every post that matches
endif;
```

Comment: It depends on the format of your `expiration_date` but basically you need to compare dates. Like e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date

Comment: if both the `$current_date` and `$expiration_date` are formatted YYYY-mm-dd... could I do this:`$current_date = date(Y-m-d); $expires = $cfs->get('expiration_date'); $today = strtotime($current_date); $expiration_date = strtotime($expires);` and then do `if ($expiration_date < $today) ) : update_post_meta($post->ID, 'premium', '1', '0'); endif; ` ? Please have a look at my code, I feel there could be mistakes.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to have a `1` or `0` returned? Couldn't you just say `$today = date("ymd");` and then `if($expiry > $today)` (with expiry also in `("ymd")` format) then show post?

Comment: Sorry just re-read - I gather that `premium` is something like sponsored posts?

Comment: @Bysander `premium` is a true/false checkbox custom field created by Custom Field Suite. I check it when I want a post to be a featured post and it then returns the value `1`. sorry. I edited that in my above post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Plugin developer helped me looking at my suggested code.

First, make sure you declare `global $cfs` (necessary when using Custom Field Suite Plugin).

The following code checks for custom field named `premium` and if its value is set to `1` (which means it's supposed to be a premium post) and also for a custom field named `expiration_date` and if a value is set.

The code then formats today's date properly to match the date format of the custom field, which is Y-m-d in this case.

After we defined and formatted the dates, the code checks if the expiration date is in the past ( `$expiration_date < $today` ) and updates the value of the `premium` field from `1` to `0`, which means it unsets the posts premium status.

**The code:**

```
global $cfs; //necessary for custom field suite plugin
if ( '1' == $cfs->get('premium') && '' != $cfs->get('expiration_date') ) : // if post has premium status and an expiration date set
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d'); // format today's date
    $expiry = $cfs->get('expiration_date');
    $today = strtotime($current_date);
    $expiration_date = strtotime($expiry);

    if ( $expiration_date < $today ) { // if expiration date is in the past
        $field_data = array('premium' => '0'); // unset premium status
        $post_data = array('ID' => $post->ID);
        $cfs->save($field_data, $post_data);
    }
endif;
```